# problems to show non personalized ads in google GDPR consent sdk

Tags: android, sdk, ads

i implemented the google consent sdk in my project, it worked till i wanted to show the ads normally when the user is out of the EEA and to show personalized or non personalized ads when he's is in the EEA. but after changing it the code doesnt give me any results.

this is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
  ConsentForm form;
  TextView textView;
  private AdView mAdView;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxx");

    showPersonalizedAds();

    textView = findViewById(R.id.simo2);

    checkForConsent();
 ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this).setDebugGeography(DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA);
}

private void checkForConsent() {
    ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    String[] publisherIds = {"pub-xxxxx"};
    ConsentInformation.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addTestDevice("xxxxxx");
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
            // User's consent status successfully updated.
            switch (consentStatus) {
                case PERSONALIZED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Showing Personalized ads");
                    showPersonalizedAds();
                    break;
                case NON_PERSONALIZED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Showing Non-Personalized ads");
                    showNonPersonalizedAds();
                    break;
                case UNKNOWN:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Consent");
                    if (ConsentInformation.getInstance(getBaseContext())
                            .isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown()) {
                        requestConsent();
                    } else {
                        showPersonalizedAds();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String errorDescription) {
            // User's consent status failed to update.
        }
    });

    // on the onCreate
}

private void requestConsent() {

    URL privacyUrl = null;
    try {
        // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy URL.
        privacyUrl = new URL("http://qisasprivacy.blogspot.com/");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle error.
    }
    form = new ConsentForm.Builder(MainActivity.this, privacyUrl)
            .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                    // Consent form loaded successfully.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Consent: onConsentFormLoaded");
                    showForm();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                    // Consent form was displayed.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Consent: onConsentFormOpened");
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormClosed(
                        ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                    // Consent form was closed.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Consent: onConsentFormClosed");
                    if (userPrefersAdFree) {
                        // Buy or Subscribe
                        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Consent: User prefers AdFree");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Consent: Requesting consent again");
                        switch (consentStatus) {
                            case PERSONALIZED:
                                showPersonalizedAds();break;
                            case NON_PERSONALIZED:
                                showNonPersonalizedAds();break;
                            case UNKNOWN:
                                showNonPersonalizedAds();break;
                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                    // Consent form error.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Consent: onConsentFormError. Error - " + errorDescription);
                }
            })
            .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .build();
// load the form so we can call .show on it after
    form.load();

}

private void showPersonalizedAds() {
    AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("xxxxxx") // Todo: Remove in Release build
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

private void showNonPersonalizedAds() {
    AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("npa", "1");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("xxxxxxx") // Todo: Remove in Release build
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

private void showForm() {
    if (form == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Consent form is null");
    }
    if (form != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Showing consent form");
        form.show();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Not Showing consent form");
    }
}
}
```

Any solutions please